# Probability in knockout games.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose in a knockout tournament 32 players p1 , p2 .....p32 participate.

In each round players are divided into pairs at random and winner goes to the next round.

If p5 reaches semifinal what is the probability that p1 wins the tournament?

All players are equally skilled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll take the statement "All players are equally skilled." to mean that every player has a $50\%$ chance to win against every other player.

$7$ players have been eliminated by $p_5$; the probability that $p_1$ was not among them is $24/31$. If $p_1$ has not been eliminated, the identity of the winner of $p_5$'s branch of the tournament is irrelevant to her; her chances of winning the tournament are still $1/32$. So the chance of $p_1$ winning the tournament, given that $p_5$ reaches the semifinal, is

$$
\frac{24}{31}\cdot\frac1{32}=\frac3{124}\;.
$$

You can also view this along the lines of Conrado's (now deleted) answer: The chance that $p_1$ reaches one of the remaining three spots in the semifinal is $3/31$, and the chance of winning the tournament once the semifinal is reached is $1/4$, again yielding

$$\frac3{31}\cdot\frac14=\frac3{124}\;.$$

And a third way to calculate: $p_5$ now has a chance of $1/4$ to win. Everyone else's chances must add up to the remaining $3/4$, and there are $31$ of them, which again yields

$$
\frac1{31}\cdot\frac34=\frac3{124}\;.
$$

Comment: There are only 5 rounds including the final.  How could have p5 eliminate 7 players.  Am I missing something.

Comment: @satishramanathan: That was perhaps not optimally formulated. I meant that $7$ players have been eliminated in the branch in which $p_5$ got to the semifinal -- if you think of it as a binary tree, $p_5$ has now reached a node under which $7$ players have been eliminated -- in this sense "he" eliminated them.

Comment: The second and the third are simpler to understand.  Great solution.